# Area 51 avatars not displaying

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, profile-picture, gravatar

For some reason, the [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants) gravatars are just displaying as an error.

Example A:

[image: Committers to Area 51 proposal]

Here we can see that for *every single user* the avatars are incorrect.

Example B: My profile on Area 51 vs my profile on *[Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)* (another Stack Exchange site)

[image: Area51 profile]

...and the Puzzling avatar...

[image: Puzzling profile avatar]

I don't know whether this is a bug on just my machine or globally for everyone, but it seems to be localized to Area 51. (I used Google Chrome on Windows 10 when encountering this error.)

Comment: No repro for me.

Comment: Firefox Nightly 96.0a1, and latest stable Chromium: no repro. `Ctrl`+`F5` the page, or look into the Network tab of your browser’s dev tools to look for network errors.

Comment: No repro on Chrome OS 93.0.4577.95 either. Area 51 gets thumbnails from `gravatar.com` instead of `i.stack.imgur.com` for you, so maybe your network is dropping requests to Gravatar?